# how to customise custom scroll?

Tags: css, scrollbar, customization

I want my scroll to have a transparent background, for the scroll to be a slight white dash and have a up arrow and down arrow at the top...this is how i am customising at the moment. It gives me a grey long scroll...but i dont know what to edit to change it?

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what to change, you need to do some research into customising Webkit scrollbars. There are quite a few tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 8):

Fist, I just want to make sure you know this only works in webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari).

Here is a more complete sample, as you can see, it takes a lot of css to get something that looks decent.

```
<head>
    <style>
    /* set the width and height */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 14px;
        height: 6px;
    }

    /* turn on the buttons at the top */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start{
        display: block;
    }
    /* turn off the buttons at the bottom */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end{
        display: none
    }


    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #666;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
        width: 50px;
        background-color: #666;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    }


    ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/corner.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner:window-inactive {
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/corner-inactive.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-resizer {
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/resizer.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: bottom right;
    }

    ::-webkit-resizer:window-inactive {
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/resizer-inactive.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:disabled {
        display: none !important;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:disabled {
        display: none !important;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:disabled {
        margin: 6px;
    }


    ::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button.png) 2 0 2 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 2px 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-background.png);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical:corner-present {
        border-bottom-width: 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical:disabled:corner-present {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical:window-inactive {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-inactive.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-background-inactive.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-thumb.png) 13 0 13 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 13px 0;
        min-height: 20px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-thumb-hover.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:active {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-thumb-active.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:window-inactive {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-thumb-inactive.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start:no-button,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start {
        margin-top: 6px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end:no-button,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end {
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end:no-button:corner-present,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end:corner-present {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }


    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start:single-button,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start:double-button,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:start {
        margin-top: -6px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end:single-button,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end:double-button,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:end {
        margin-bottom: -6px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical:disabled {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track-disabled.png) 13 0 13 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 13px 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:decrement {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track.png) 13 0 13 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 13px 0 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:decrement:hover {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track-hover.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:decrement:active {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track-active.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:increment {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track.png) 13 0 13 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 0 0 13px 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:increment:hover {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track-hover.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical:increment:active {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-track-active.png) 13 0 13 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical {
        height: 20px;
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button.png) 2 0 2 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-width: 2px 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-decrement-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
        background-position: 3px 3px, 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-hover.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-decrement-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background-hover.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:active {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-active.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-decrement-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background-active.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:window-inactive {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-inactive.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-decrement-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background-inactive.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-increment-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
        background-position: 3px 8px, 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:hover {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-hover.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-increment-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background-hover.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:active {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-active.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-increment-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background-active.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:window-inactive {
        -webkit-border-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-button-inactive.png) 2 0 2 0;
        background-image: url(http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/resources/vertical-increment-arrow.png), url(resources/vertical-button-background-inactive.png);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:double-button:vertical:start:decrement,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:decrement,
     {
        height: 14px;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        background-position: 3px 3px, 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:double-button:vertical:start:increment,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment{
        background-position: 3px 4px, 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:double-button:vertical:end:decrement,
     {
        background-position: 3px 8px, 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:double-button:vertical:end:increment {
        height: 14px;
        border-top-width: 0;
        background-position: 3px 4px, 0 0;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment:corner-present {
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        height: 19px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:double-button:vertical:end:increment:corner-present,
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment:corner-present {
        height: 13px;
    }    
</style>
<body class="double-start">
enter code here
</body>
```