# CSS vertical scrollbar padding left/right in UL possible?

Tags: css, scrollbar

Is it possible to add padding or margin around the scrollbar item or scrollbar-track?  I've tried and can only get padding top/bottom.  Adding padding to the UL has no effect on scrollbar.  Negative margins on scrollbar have no effect.  Ideas?  [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9z2qy/).

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
margin:10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can see an example below, basically forget adding margin or padding there, just increase the width/height of scroll area, and decrease the width height of thumb/track.

Quoted from [how to customise custom scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226059/how-to-customise-custom-scroll)

```css
body {
  min-height: 1000px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

div#content {
  height: 1000px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content" contenteditable>
    Click to type...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, the magic here is `background-clip: padding-box` which causes the border of the element to be cut off (along with the background color under it), so by setting the border to a fully transparent color it will cause a padding effect matching the border's width. Without that rule the background color would be visible through the border.

Comment: bizarrely, this fails to work when you want to increase the gap, increase it's width and preserve the round borders. any tips?

Comment: okay this is a bit better : `::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 40px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 12px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);;
 }` the real shame is that I can't add top and bottom margin.

Comment: Thanks @Bora Alp Arat: How did you get the height to work? No matter what I do, even copying your entire code (for the scrollbars only), it doesn't work.

Comment: @tatsu top and bottom works with this other answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034019/1633985

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox or iOS. Tried to edit, but edit queue is full.

Answer (score 20):

I created a margin-right effect using border-right on the scrollbar-thumb:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
  border-right: 4px white solid;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

The scrollbar appears to have width 4px and margin-right 4px.

Here's a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/4kgvL93h/3/

Comment: This approach doesn't support border radius.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use the **margin-block**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px F2F2F2; 
   border-radius: 0px;
   margin-block: 15px;
}
```

```css
#container{
    height:400px;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border-radius:25px;  
}

#content{
    height:700px;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:25px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 5px;
}
  
  /* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px F2F2F2; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-block: 25px;
}
   
  /* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
     background: #8B8B8B; 
     border-radius: 27px;
     border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <br>
    Click to type...
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the desired effect in your own example.

Comment: change margin-block 15px and 25 px to 0px in css to see the effect on scroll-bar

Answer (score 7):

You can add a margin to the scrollbar track;

```
#someID ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  border-radius: 15px;
   margin: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 7px 10px 12px #f0f0f0;
  
 }
```

Comment: this only seems to apply a top and bottom margin

Answer (score 6):

This solution make a real space between content and scrollbar (if a scrollable element doesn't have a transparent background). Useful for window scrollbars.

```
.scroll {overflow:auto;}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background:inherit;
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical {
    border-right:8px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    border-right:8px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    border-bottom:8px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    border-bottom:8px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
    .scroll::-webkit-resizer {background:inherit;
    border-right:8px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2); //optional
    border-bottom:8px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2); //optional
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another important attribute to add vertical or horizontal margin:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `border-radius`, neither `box-shadow` works properly nor does `background-clip: padding-box`.

I created a parent div on top of the div which needs scrolling. And fixed the height of parent div and put padding right in the child div. That worked well for my case.

```
<div class="parent h-10 overflow-scroll">
 <div class="scroll child pr-2">
     <!-- CONTENT -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just add an outer div to the scrollable div and put some padding right on the outer div

Comment: Hi William, if you can create a fiddle it will be better to understand.