# Dropdown Scroll Bar Position

Tags: html, css, sass

So far I have achieved this:
[image: Now]

What I want is the scroll bar position on the right side with padding. Something like this:
[image: To achieve]
My HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <div id="dropdown-label" class="dropdown-active" data-toggle="dropdown"  title="{{selected.label}}">
          <i class="g2icon-user-dropdown dropdown-entity-icon"></i> {{ selected.label }}
          <span class="right-icon glyph-2 fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-label" lr-infinite-scroll="loadMore">
          <!-- My Organizations-->
          <li class="col-md-12 full-s calendar-list-break">
            <span>My Organization</span>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-12 full-s calendar-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: 'organization'" title="{{item.label}}">
            <span ng-click="selectOption(item.id)"><i class="dropdown-entity-icon"></i> {{item.label}}</span>
          </li>

          <!-- My Groups -->
          <li class="col-md-12 full-s calendar-list-break">
            <span>My Groups</span>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-12 full-s calendar-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: 'group'" title="{{item.label}}">
            <span ng-click="selectOption(item.id)"><i class=" dropdown-entity-icon"></i> {{item.label}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.dropdown {
@include modal-scrollbar; //etc etc
}
```

My SASS mixin looks like this:

```
@mixin custom-scrollbar() {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px darkgrey;
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this? 
Thank you.
NOTE: I didn't find something useful googling around.

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: Sure. HTML added.

Comment: If you can provide some working demo. It would be great.

Comment: My problem description is very simple. I just want scroll bar position on the right with some little padding-left.

Comment: Are you using some plugin for scroll bar or it's default?

Comment: Yes, it is just a default scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867972/6202039)
It has added a position and set the right property of the parent div element(In this case your dropdown class) hence the overall effect will look like the same as you want.