# How to make the scrollbar spacing/padding/margin with CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is current scrollbar I working on.

[Scrollbar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqDF2.png)

```
//The overflow div
div {
width: 100%;
overflow: overlay;
}

//Scroll Bar CSS
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:14px;}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #4b49499c;border-radius: 50px;}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: transparent;}
```

I want to make the scrollbar have some spacing/padding/margin on right site, instead of scrollbar fully attached to the end of right. I tried to reduce the div width size. this does work for creating some right space for the scrollbar, but the children div inside it the width is reduce together.

[After Reducing the width of div Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqDF2.png)

```
   //The overflow div
    div {
    width: 96%;
    overflow: overlay;
    }
    
    //Scroll Bar CSS
    ::-webkit-scrollbar{width:14px;}
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #4b49499c;border-radius: 50px;}
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: transparent;}
```

And here is the sample result that I want.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pclnY.png)

Anyone have idea on how to make this happen?

Comment: Can you provide a demo of your code using CodePen? It's much easier for other people to answer your questions.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gerardhaw/pen/mdmVjeZ
I just did a simple CodePen here.

Comment: Look at the following answer for some more inputs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866759/how-do-i-add-a-margin-to-a-css-webkit-scrollbar