# Website scrollbar becoming invisible when small

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webkit, scrollbar

I am using the -webkit-scrollbar pseudo elements to customize the scrollbar on a React web-app for desktop webkit browsers.  It is being used for scrolling through messages in a 'chat-box' like element whose overflow-y property is set to 'auto'. For the most part, this functions properly as can be seen in the image below (grey scrollbar at right):

[image]

As more messages are added, the height of the grey scrollbar thumb naturally decreases. An issue arises when the message box is populated with many long messages:

**The thumb seems to become smaller and smaller, until it disappears.** The scrolling functionality still works. This can be seen in the image below (scrollbar at right is gone):

[image]

Below is the css code which styles the scrollbar (in order to create a 'padding' for the scrollbar, I used the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684101/css-vertical-scrollbar-padding-left-right-in-ul-possible)):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 24px; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 9px solid rgba(248, 230, 230, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

I unsuccessfully attempted to resolve this by adding `min-height: 5px;` to the scrollbar.

[JSFiddle (Add more letters to see scrollbar disappear)](https://jsfiddle.net/x2ahsztd/1/).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ave you tried with a different phone?

Comment: And also the scrollbar seems to be related to the messages list component, not to the whole page

Comment: @Emanuele This is not mobile, this is desktop. And it is not related to the component, I just tested it with the whole page - same issue.

Comment: can you provide a sandbox to try?

Comment: @Emanuele Added a sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with `background-clip: padding-box;`.

When the content becomes too long its height becomes 0

Add `min-height` with larger height than 5px (something like 30px) and it'll work fine.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 24px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border: 9px solid rgba(248, 230, 230, 0);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  min-height: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
 <div>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

    </div>
```

Comment: So you need `min-height` try to put it larger value, something like `30px`. It worked fine with me

Comment: Bingo you got it nice job. Perhaps you can place that in your answer so people will see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile browsers automatically hide the scrollbar when not scrolling. The reason for that is to allow more space to be used by content, in an already small-width environment.

While scrolling the scrollbar should be visible, and disappear when you stop scrolling, as you can see in this unstyled example (open in mobile/mobile mode. on desktop you might have to refresh after starting mobile mode to see the effect correctly):

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, odit ratione saepe in molestiae, nesciunt recusandae voluptas corrupti ex autem fugiat commodi totam exercitationem laboriosam suscipit facilis non optio iusto.</p> (repeat many times)
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXBZRX

Comment: This is for desktop browsers, not mobile