# How to make the padding in scrollbar? CSS

Tags: css

I've tried everything, searched the whole stack overflow and google.
Can someone help me to make this particular type of scrollbar?
When I use the border-right/top/bottom to make the spaces around it, it breaks the border-radius and gets ugly. As a reference, it's the same scrollbar used in Googledocs, a slim, rounded and doesn't touch the margins of the page: https://docs.new/

Here's the image: [rounded, slim and not touching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpnv.png)

So far I got:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: #262338;
  width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  padding: 0 4px;
  background: #6E7191;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

Comment: do you have any code that you tried as a jumping off point?

Comment: added what I got (nothing)

Comment: **Duplicate**
Look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684101/css-vertical-scrollbar-padding-left-right-in-ul-possible

Comment: It's not duplicate!! Unfortunately this one only the scrollbar-thumb doesn't reach the borders, not the scrollbar itself :( This way I can only use with the scrollbar the same color as the div, and in my image example I have 3 different colors (container background, scrollbar background and scrollbar thumb background). But thanks, Silas!!

Comment: I tried to match your example as close as possible on both chrome and Firefox without using any 3d parties. If you are using Firefox, the actual results of it will not show up in the snippet and it has no support for rounded corners. I suggest you try the result in your project on both browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scrollbar Padding

I think you'll have to use a container to accomplish the **not touching** part of your requirements.

### Chrome vs Firefox

*Be aware that the support to adjust the scrollbar is **very limited in firefox compared to chrome** browsers. The result of it will not show up in this snippet, nor on websites like jsfiddle. Rounded corners are impossible to achieve in firefox without using your own implementation or a third party library like [thisone](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar) for example.*

### Example

```css
body {
  background-color: #14142B;
}

/* FIREFOX */

html {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #6E7191 #262338;
}

/* CHROME */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #262338;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6E7191;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #7E81A1;
}

.container {
  margin: 1.5rem .5rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
}

.content {
  height: 25rem;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #201F36;
}

.filler {
  height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="filler"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 34px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

This would get you the main design of the scrollbar you are looking. This is what I used on my website. Hope this is the design you want!

Comment: Hi Jeff! Thanks for your help. Does yours have right and top-bottom padding? I've tried here and it's not working :( This little padding is what I'm not able to make!!

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for your kindness! I'm still getting the scrollbar "touching" the margin. See how in https://docs.new/ is a bit separated?

Comment: If you want it off the margin on the right side, you would need to edit the body of the css file. For example .body{margin: 5px;}. Let me know if that settles the issue for you

Comment: This does not work because it's not about the content but the scrollbar. I appreciate, tho!

Comment: I am just a bit confused on what you are trying to achieve. Could you show me a pic of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, there's one in my question! :)

Comment: Okay. I checked how to create those types of scrollbars and the best way to receive that margin would be to do: .body{margin-right: 5px;}

Comment: unfortunately that does not work because it moves the element and not the scrollbar. Mine is inside a dropdown menu in a search bar! but thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding padding-right: 5px for the dropdown menu?

Comment: yes, it moves everything but the scrollbar is always fixed!

Comment: Have you tried using transform:scaleX(0.95) on the scrollbar?

Comment: Jeff, this property does not work on scrollbars! If you find a solution that works for you let me know. Have a good evening.