# Add margin between scroll bar and border

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, styled-components, margin

I want to add a margin between the scroll bar and the right border of the text area.
I tried adding margin-right / left values to the -webkit-scrollbar but nothing works for me.
This is my style component :

```
const FormTextArea = styled.textarea`
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
padding: 12px;
width: 316px;
height: 216px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid ${props => props.error ? '#B42F08' : '#809BAF'};
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top: 16px;
margin-left: 20px;
&:focus {
    border: 1px solid #3BB0C9 ;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #B3B4B6;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
resize:none;
   &::placeholder {
        color:#808285
    }
    &:focus , &:active {
        outline: none !important;
    }
`;
```

This is what my text area looks like :

[image: This is how my text area looks like :]

I want the scroll bar to be as he is right now but with a 4px margin from the border

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684101/css-vertical-scrollbar-padding-left-right-in-ul-possible

Comment: Can you create a reproducible snippet so we could play around with your code?

Answer (score 0):

```css
const FormTextArea = styled.textarea`
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
padding: 12px;
width: 316px;
height: 216px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid ${props => props.error ? '#B42F08' : '#809BAF'};
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top: 16px;
margin-left: 20px;
&:focus {
    border: 1px solid #3BB0C9 ;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #B3B4B6;
    border-right: 10px white solid;
  }
resize:none;
   &::placeholder {
        color:#808285
    }
    &:focus , &:active {
        outline: none !important;
    }
`;
```

You could just add a border-right to the `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` and make the `::-webkit-scrollbar` wider.