# Background-clip: padding-box doesn't work for a thick transparent border

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, background-clip

I'm trying to customize scrollbar appearance using the [invisible borders solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684101/css-vertical-scrollbar-padding-left-right-in-ul-possible).
It works well, except for some edge cases, probably when the border width is too sick.
Here's an example:

```css
.box,
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;  
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track, 
.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-width: 20px 15px 0px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #D2D2D2;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 22px;
    width: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
}

.box.is-fixed::-webkit-scrollbar-track, 
.box.is-fixed::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>Scrollbar styled incorrectly:</p>

<div class='box'>
  <div class='content'>
  
  </div>
</div>

<p>Desired style:</p>

<div class='box is-fixed'>
  <div class='content'>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Some ways to fix that (don't know why they work):

- set border-radius from 3px to 0 or 1px
- set top border width to 19px instead of 20px

Why the original solution doesn't work and why fixes above help?

Comment: Could you describe what the edge cases are as I'm not sure I'm seeing the problem at the moment.

Comment: Sure, sorry for confusion. I've added a sample <div> with correct styles below the problematic one. Can you see the difference?